# Typescript assign null to a type don't trigger error

Tags: angular, typescript

Can anyone explain me, please, why this code dont trigger an error?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

interface Animal{
  name: string;
}

@Injectable()
export class AnimalService {
  lion: Animal = null;
  constructor() {}
  get(){
   return this.lion;
 }
}
```

Comment: By default in JavaScript(and Typescript) any field can have the value null or undefined, have a look at [stricktNullCheck](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/7140).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set `"strictNullChecks": true` in your `tsconfig.json` for it to throw error when you do `lion: Animal = null;`.

See the [documentation for `strictNullChecks` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html):

> In strict null checking mode, the null and undefined values are not in
>   the domain of every type and are only assignable to themselves and any
>   (the one exception being that undefined is also assignable to void).

Also see: https://ariya.io/2016/10/typescript-2-and-strict-null-checking

Comment: So what's the best options put the flag to false or set it to true and using a syntax like const lunchBox: Nullable<Food>[] = [];

Comment: That depends on your requirements. I personally turn on `strictNullChecks` and use `variable: Type | null` for specific cases where nulls can be allowed.

Comment: It just becomes a nightmare because now you have to typecast every time you set a value. You cannot set it to a string value because the compiler will say it doesn't  match the defined type string | null

Comment: @Spock use the non null assertion operator: `!`. E.g `someNonNullMethod(someNullabeValue!)`

Comment: @mdsimmo yep, it just feels like a hack :) ..  but yeah good point, thanks

Answer (score 3):

use `variable: Type | null` for specific cases where nulls can be allowed.

ex: `name:string| null`

I personally turn on `strictNullChecks` and use the specific cases.